# Java - Custom JSlider will not update

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, jslider

I have a custom component based on the JSlider. It's essentially the same thing only it has 2 thumbs, which I named a DualSlider.

I need to change the maximum value of the slider once in a while, so every time I do, I call updateUI to reflect this.

```
public void updateUI() {
    this.setUI(new DualSliderUI(this));
    this.updateLabelUIs();
}
```

However, the maximum value of the DualSlider when I try to use it is still set at the original value no matter how many times I try to change it while using my program. I can confirm with a few println statements that a new DualSliderUI is being made with the slider that has the new max value, but for whatever reason the original DualSliderUI I initialized the slider with is the one that is in use.

What other things do I have to make sure I do when I update a property so I can avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

1) I can't see reason for usage `updateUI()` this should be done once time, only when you built this `JSlider`, never do that repeately

2) you have look at [BoundedRangeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/class-use/BoundedRangeModel.html), [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617605/java-jslider-precision-problems)